# Can a deck be unfrozen by only using the top card

Tags: canasta

If the deck is frozen, I know it can only be unfrozen by having a natural pair from your hand and using the top card to meld.  My question is… if you only want the top card, do you have to take the whole deck and if you are able to only take the top card, is the deck now unfrozen, even if there is still a wild in it?

Answer (score 3):

You can never pick up only the top card of the discard pile.

You always either pick up the entire discard pile, or draw from the regular draw pile. This does not change at all whether the pile is frozen or not. The pile being frozen makes it harder to pick up the discard pile, but it doesn't affect the fact that you can only pick up the entire pile.

From [the rules](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/):

> When the players turn comes, a player is always entitled to draw the top card of the stock. Or, if the player wishes, they may instead (subject to restrictions under "Taking the Discard Pile") take the top card of the discard pile to use it in a meld; having done so, **they must take the rest of the discard pile**.

> TAKING THE DISCARD PILE
>
> > Having taken and melded the top discard as described, the player takes the rest of the pile into their hand and may then meld some or all of the additional cards as they please.